# Auto Select Dynamic Dropdown Matching value of php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i want to automatically select value of dropdown matching value of php variable

here is my

```
    <select class="destinationId" id="destination" name="destinationId" onchange="getNationalityAndLiving(this.value,'','');">
                  <option value="" disabled selected>Select Traveling to</option>
                                <option data-prefix="azerbaijan" value="azerbaijan" >
                  Azerbaijan              </option>
                                <option data-prefix="cambodia" value="cambodia" >
                  Cambodia              </option>
                                <option data-prefix="egypt" value="egypt" >
                  Egypt              </option>
                                <option data-prefix="india" value="india" >
                  India              </option>
                                <option data-prefix="kenya" value="kenya" >
                  Kenya              </option>
                              </select>


<select class="nationality" name="nationality" id="nationality">
              <option value="" disabled selected>Select Citizen of</option>
            </select>
```

this is my ajax code to retrive dynamic dropdown for select select option "nationality"

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#destination").change(function(){
        var deptid = $(this).val();
        var dbnm = "country";
        var res = dbnm.concat(deptid);
        $('.overlay').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getcountry.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {dest:res},
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(response){
                var len = response.length;

                $("#nationality").empty();
                for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                    var id = response[i]['id'];
                    var name = response[i]['name'];

                    $("#nationality").append("<option data-nation='"+name+"' value='"+name+"'>"+name+"</option>");

                }
               $('.overlay').hide();            
            }
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

i have some dynamic php variable coming on this page from previous url.
for example

```
$nationality = "some value";
```

What i want is selected dropdown with value of $nationality in second dropdown,

if it was static i could have achieved this, but how to auto select in dynamic i am not able to get any workaround.

Comment: How do you store `$nationality` and how do you render it?

Comment: this the same dropdowns, i am using on my previous page to pass data to this page with some additional informations of $nationality .

Comment: i pass this $nationality using codeigniter controller segments.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the php variable to js variable

```
var Nationality = "<?php echo $nationality; ?>";
```

then when append the `option` you can use

```
$("#nationality").append("<option data-nation='"+name+"' value='"+name+"' "+ (Nationality.trim() == name.trim()) ? 'selected' : '' +">"+name+"</option>");
```

Comment: It should be "var Nationality = '<?php echo $nationality; ?>';"

Comment: @DuyNguyenHoang yes.. Thank you :-)

Comment: No its not working, when i used append option it stopped showing fetched options in dropdown,